# How to show scroller indicator in NSTableview when scrolling , hide when not scrolling

Tags: macos, nstableview

I am new in MacOS ,I want to show scroller indicator in NSTableview when scrolling , hide when not scrolling.
I am thinking to get the delegate of NSScroller , So i can detect when it scrolls,then hide/show it . Please help

Comment: Once you hide it after end scrolling then how it's possible to scroll it again?

Comment: I mean hide the  scroller indicator,any idea?@Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: Do you want to override the user preference in system prefs?

Comment: If it works ,sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [NSTableView reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview):

> Table views are displayed in scroll views.

A table view itself doesn't know how to scroll. You have to put it inside a scroll view in order to scroll the table. If you're used to iOS and UIKit, that's a difference; `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so on that platform a table view *is* a scroll view. In a MacOS project, if you insert a table into a view in Xcode's nib or storyboard editor, Xcode will actually insert a scroll view that contains a table view so you'll already have what you need. If you're creating the table in code, you'll need to also create the scroll view yourself.

Looking at [NSScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollview), there's a property called `autohidesScrollers` which is...

> A Boolean that indicates whether the scroll view automatically hides its scroll bars when they are not needed.

So, to get the behavior you're asking for, you need to set the scroll view's `autohidesScrollers` property to `YES`.

Of course, you can set that in the storyboard editor too, but again you need to look at the options for the scroll view, not the table view:

[image: scroll view options]